# Searching a MySQL table, using PHP, for multiple fields in an auto complete box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, autocomplete

Im trying to search two of the fields in my table. (Database table contains cocktail names, with their name, ingredients and description) When a user types their desired term into the search box, auto complete results are given using Ajax/jquery.

I've got it working searching one field (Name) but can't seem to get it to do more than the one(Name & Ingredients). Another problem is when the results are given (they are given as links) When you select them it puts the data in the entry box instead of taking you to the next page.

index.php:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
</script>

    <label>Tag:</label>
    <input name="tag" type="text" id="tag" size="40"/>
```

autocomplete.php:

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','ignitet1','password','ignitet1_WhatCocktail') or die("Database Error");
    $sql="SELECT Name FROM tblCocktail WHERE Name LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY Name";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    if($result)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<a href=\"details.php\">";
            echo $row['Name']."," , "<br />";
            echo "</a>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well one thing for sure, you are only looking for the valye 'Name" in your query .. so thats all you are going to get.. if you have two fields Name and Ingredients perhaps you should include it in the select statement and fix the where clause to do a OR clause.  WHERE NAME LIKE '%$MY_DATA%' OR INGREDIENTS LIKE '%$MY_DATA%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about forcing a link to that page, but for a quick and dirty fix on the search I would add:
`OR Ingredients LIKE '%$my_dat%'`
before the ORDER clause.

**Update:**

user710502 is correct about the fields to be selected in the query. As for the autocomplete, I looked at the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) and it looks like you will have to create a custom event handler for the autocompleteselect event. This event fires when the user chooses an option from the dropdown. The default behavior (as you know) is to fill the field with the 'value'. Your added code will look something like this:

```
$("#selector-for-field").bind('autocompleteselect',function(event,ui){
    event.preventDefault(); // this will stop the field from filling
    // maybe make the value sent from the serverside a hyperlink,
    // eg. http://www.wherever.com/you/want/the/item/to/link-to
    // then in here do something like:
    window.location(ui.item.value);
});
```

You'll have to double check that `ui.item.value` works because I didn't check it.

Comment: I've tried 
   "SELECT Name AND Ingredients FROM tblCocktail WHERE Name LIKE %$my_data%' OR Ingredients LIKE '%$my_data%'";

the dropdown box now appears all the time but doesn't show results

Comment: The AND does not go there man, it would be something like ** SELECT NAME, INGREDIENTS FROM tblCocktail WHERE Name Name LIKE %$my_data%' OR Ingredients LIKE '%$my_data%'

Comment: ah that did fix the problem of it not displaying, only problem now is the fact that when clicked the code just gets put into the text entry box instead of it behaving as a link

Comment: i updated my answer with info on the autocomplete issue. I see that you are new to stack overflow. if my answer is what you are looking for click the check mark next to it to "accept" it. thanks